# xml add Third time return error wp8 "no white space characters are allowed"

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8-emulator

When i am add xml file in second time return a error how to solved this problem 
First time run a else code to add file in isolated storage second time if file exit code is run and add one more xml element and when i am try to add Third time return a error error in my image file Help me .
Here is my code

```
private void AddXml(List<Bookmarkdata> data ,string filename, string fileid,string fullpath,string currentpage)
    {

        XDocument doc = null;
        TextWriter writer = null;
        XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
        xmlWriterSettings.Indent = true;
        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists("BookmarkFile.xml"))
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("BookmarkFile.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {

                    XDocument _doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
                    XElement _item = new XElement("Bookmarkdata");
                    XAttribute Bookname = new XAttribute("Bookname", filename);
                    XAttribute Bookid = new XAttribute("Bookid", fileid);
                    XAttribute BookPath = new XAttribute("BookPath", fullpath);
                    XAttribute Pageno = new XAttribute("Pageno", currentpage);
                    _item.Add(Bookname, Bookid, BookPath, Pageno);
                    _doc.Root.Add(new XElement(_item));
                    _doc.Save(stream);

                  }

            }
            else
            {
                using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("BookmarkFile.xml", FileMode.Create))
                {
                    writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Bookmarkdata>));
                    // using (XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xmlWriterSettings))
                    // {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
                    // }
                }
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete solution to your problem, just suggestion on how to trace root cause of the problem.

The exception is indeed complaining about your file containing invalid XML content. Try to look at it more closely, for example, by printing XML file content :

```
//add this code block inside inner using block
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string xmlContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
MessageBox.Show(text);
```

Moreover, in the same way you can see how your code add xml element each time, so you can spot flaws in the program logic more easily and fix it.

Comment: here i comment my xml file please Help